# How do fonts / fallback fonts work in Android 9+?

Tags: 9.0-pie, fonts, magisk

Short story
I want to add a fallback font to my OP6t running Android 9 to support poorly updated / coded legacy apps (unlocked, and rooted with Magisk)
- I am looking for a system wide solution 
I am not having any luck figuring out what I am doing wrong

Long story
Android 4-8 I just rooted the device, copied a modified DroidSansFallback.ttf and corrected the permissions -- now I am at Android 9 and this doesn't appear to work

I have tried (via Magisk Module)
- injecting the font to system/fonts
- injecting system/etc modified fonts.xml & fonts_slate.xml

Any help suggestions or ideas is greatly appreciated!